# Features spanning multiple sprints in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to organize the work for my team in Azure Devops and have started to break down my work into the work item types provided: Epics, Features and Backlog Items. My understanding is that the Features are a collection of related stories that don't necessarily fit into a single sprint, that is they are a portfolio management thing (a folder).

When I create a Plan I can choose to display Features, but I can only have a feature assigned to a single sprint at any one time. How can I get features showing in a Plan across multiple sprints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a "right" way to do this, but I personally would assign Features to the last sprint in which all User Stories will be delivered. Likewise I would do the same between Epics and Features.

Features and Epics are expected to be completed over multiple sprints, so the notion of using a sprint assignment to show when they're going to be "worked on" (like a User Story) is really replaced by when all components of that feature will be delivered. That's how I'm using them anyway.

Comment: I think this is the best that can be done using the vanilla functionality. I have however found an extension called 'Feature timeline and Epic Roadmap' that allows what I wanted as it draws it's graph using the start and end dates.

Comment: @AndyDavies Can you please share that extension URL? Thanks!

Comment: @tatlar The extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.workitem-feature-timeline-extension

Answer (score 3):

If you set the start and end dates of the feature, it will span across multiple sprints.

Comment: This works beautifully and should be the updated answer.